# how do I exclude urls to be crawled in php

Tags: php

Hey there folks :) I am writing a search engine in php, but would like to exclue certain urls from being crawled, e.g. cart, checkout pages and log in pages. The problem here might be that I want to crawl non-english sites. I also want to exclude social media - facebook and instgram pages and have included the following

I have tried this:

```
mb_strpos($url, 'kasse', "UTF-8") !== false
```

but this returned a **syntax error for UTF**, so I tried taking away the "" surrounding UTF-8, so I tried with single quotes '' and even without anything around UTF - though I got errors for that too, so I decided to take out the UTF bit entirely. but I am guessing this isn't right either because now my crawler isn't working period

```
    getDetails($href);
} 
if (mb_strpos($url, 'facebook') !== false || mb_strpos($url, 'twitter') !== false || mb_strpos($url, 'cart.php') !== false || mb_strpos($url, 'kurv') !== false || mb_strpos($url, 'konta') !== false || mb_strpos($url, 'Konta') !== false || mb_strpos($url, 'konto') !== false || mb_strpos($url, 'password') !== false || mb_strpos($url, 'loyniorð') !== false || mb_strpos($url, 'kasse') !== false || mb_strpos($url, 'login') !== false || mb_strpos($url, 'Kurv') !== false || mb_strpos($url, 'Kassi') !== false || mb_strpos($url, 'checkout') !== false || mb_strpos($url, 'Takk-fyri') !== false) 
{    
    return;
```

the urls keep getting crawled despite my best efforts

Comment: mb_strpos takes the encoding as _fourth_ parameter - you tried to supply `UTF-8` as _third_, which is the offset to search from.

Comment: You can also use the robots.txt many pages include to set what to crawl and what to not crawl, instead of maintaining your own list

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
mb_strpos($url, 'kasse', "UTF-8") !== false
```

should be

```
mb_strpos($url, 'kasse', 0, "UTF-8") !== false
```

Comment: Thanks a mil for this example :) been struggling with this for AGES :)